# Reading struct from text file

Tags: c, file

I need to  read a `struct` from a file but my code doesnt work. 
How can I reach end of file

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct elements {
   char CallType;
   int noofcparty,nooPartyBcalling,id,number_of_packets,roaming_option;

} Elements;

int main()
{  
    Elements e;
    FILE *ptr_file;
    char buf[1000];
    ptr_file =fopen("save_data.txt","r");
    fclose(ptr_file);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: If you want to store and retrieve the binary in-memory representation of the struct, you can use `fwrite` and `fread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume the file is in CSV (Comma-separated values).
example:  b,100,200,800,45.

```
char line[200];
int max_size_line=200;
while(fgets(line,max_size_line,ptr_file)!=0)//read line by line until the end
    {    sscanf(line,"%c,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&CallType,&noofcparty,&nooPartyBcalling,&id,&number_of_packets,&roaming_option);
          }
```